# Search Email Using Headers In Microsoft Graph API

Tags: python, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

I want to search email based on the header present in the email using Microsoft Graph API. In message headers we have **DKIM-Signature** field, I want to search all emails that do not contain `abc.com` domain in their **DKIM-Signature** field.

```
v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=abc.com;
```

I want to do it using Microsoft graph api.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the dkim-signature extended property eg

[image]

Then use a advanced query https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/aad-advanced-queries and either contains or startswith eg to find all email that have a particular part of DKIM sig

```html
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailfolders('Inbox')/messages?$filter=singleValueExtendedProperties/Any(ep:+ep/id+eq+'String {00020386-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}+Name+dkim-signature'+and+contains(ep/value,'v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;        d=blah-com.xxxx.blahsmtp.com'))&$count=true&Select=Subject,From&$Expand=SingleValueExtendedProperties($filter=(Id eq 'String {00020386-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}+Name+dkim-signature'))
```

or in your example you can negate that query with a not eg

```html
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailfolders('Inbox')/messages?$filter=NOT  singleValueExtendedProperties/Any(ep:+ep/id+eq+'String {00020386-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}+Name+dkim-signature'+and+startswith(ep/value,'v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;        d=blah-com.xxxxx.blah.com'))&$count=true&Select=Subject,From&$Expand=SingleValueExtendedProperties($filter=(Id eq 'String {00020386-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}+Name+dkim-signature'))
```

[image]

Comment: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailfolders('Inbox')/messages?$filter=singleValueExtendedProperties/Any(ep:+ep/id+eq+'String {00020386-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}+Name+dkim-signature'+and+contains(ep/value,'d=gmail.com'))&$count=true&Select=Subject


I tried to search all emails that came from Gmail, I manually verified the header in one of the emails that came from Gmail and it contains it but I am not getting valid results from the above query. 
I am getting 0 count from the above search query

Comment: Did you add the consistencylevel: eventual header to your query ? when i try this with the Graph explorer (see added screenshot) it works fine